# Why does running web application in Chrome through Visual Studio freezes Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, typescript, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I have a web application project that I'm running in Visual Studio 2017.  The project uses Web API, AngularJS, and Typescript.  When I click to debug the application and IIS Express starts up, VS opens Chrome, but the default page doesn't load.  Worse, Visual Studio freezes.

I've found that a workaround whereby I reload the default page in Chrome to make the default page appear and to unfreeze VS.

What can I do so that VS doesn't freeze and the default page loads when I open the application in Chrome?  The only potential solution I could find was to disable Javascript debugging in Chrome, but I need that.

Note: I have a different problem when I use Internet Explorer.

Comment: You may need to dive into Task Manager / Process Explorer to locate the specific source of the problem... i.e. which process is being greedy, is it Chrome, Visual Studio, IIS, something else... or all of the above?

Comment: @Fenton I checked the Task Manager and neither VS nor Chrome will killing my CPU.  Both had pretty low usage in fact.  I noticed that if I open an HTML file in VS, and then click to debug the application, Chrome opens that HTML file no problem.  And VS doesn't freeze.  This doesn't work with my default file which is a cshtml file however.

Comment: That's interesting - do you have Browser Link enabled? If so, what happens if you disable it and try again?

Comment: @Fenton, I still get the same problem after disabling Browser Link.  I tried it a couple of times.

Comment: Last test... what about if you "Start without debugging"?

Comment: @Fenton, That works.  "Start without debugging".  That's not an ideal solution however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156944/discussion-between-fenton-and-user2023861).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slightly unfortunate answer is that lots of people are having a problem when debugging against Chrome with JavaScript debugging enabled.

There are two solutions, neither of which are perfect.

1. De-select the "Enable JavaScript debugging for asp.net (Chrome and IE)" option in Visual Studio settings
2. Manually enter the address (or refresh it as you have been).

Follow the [issue tracker](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39945/visual-studio-freezes-in-debug-with-chrome.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the similar kind of issue. My Visual studio is crashing when I try to debug the application with enable JavaScript so this fix works for me.
Go on the Tools > options > Debugging > General > Uncheck these two options which have text as: Enable using the multi-target JavaScript debugger for debugging. > enable /checked Enable JavaScript debugger for ASP.NET.

[Uncheck these two highlighted options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3WSW.png)